Add plugins to Eclipse RCP product contents
I was given an Eclipse RCP application with a file named MyApp.product.
I noticed that the app is not working since many plugins are missing (red cross on Eclipse UI) in MyApp.product, product configuration contents. E.g. slf4j.api is marked with a red cross.
Can anyone more expert tell me how to solve this issue?

Among other things you need to set up a target platform. Eclipse Target Platform tutorial

@greg-449 how this should solve the issue?

Setting up an unknown RCP is far too broad a topic for Stack Overflow. For a start read the tutorial I linked and try defining the target platform.
